# mstest failing to start

Tags: mstest

The `run.mstest` command is inititated but the following error message displays.  No logs are generated nor are any tests run, but the build is reported as successful.

```
 [exec] 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe' failed to start.
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to find more information.  Can you open up a Visual Studio Command Prompt and run your 'mstest' against your test assembly to see what output you get?